# mpv restart RTP stream after server stops and starts

Tags: rtp, sdp, mpv

I have a local server that starts two GStreamer pipelines to my computer, but it needs to stop and start the streams occasionally. I am using a lavfi-complex to stack the streams as well. When the server stops the stream and starts again (to the same IP address and ports) I get a flood of this message:

```
sdp: RTP: dropping old packet received too late
```

I start the streams by `loadfile` then `video-add` then settings `lavfi-filter` property to `[vid1][vid2] vstack [vo]`. If I only have one stream and no filter (just loadfile) I can stop the server, start it again, and run loadfile again and the files load. However with a lavfi-filter, the documentation says:

> It's not possible to change the tracks connected to the filter at runtime, unless you explicitly change the lavfi-complex property and set new track assignments. When the graph is changed, the track selection is changed according to the used labels as well.

I can change the lavfi-filter property to an empty string, send a loadfile command again, and then set the lavfi-filter back, but the output stays blank. I tried loadfile and video-reload with id=2 for the second video but the video-reload command fails.

Is there a sequence of commands that can cause mpv to stop and reload the streams? Or even better, some configuration parameters that will make it not drop old packets?